# Simple friendship relationship between users in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, relationship

Hi could someone explain to me how I would write a simple friendship relationship in mongoose

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var User = new Schema({

username:{
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
},
password:{
    type: String,
    required: true
},
friends:{[

    // stuck here How would i define what another user is here
]}
}

});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
friends: [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "User"}]
```